# OOP select query works but unsure how to process the results

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm turning my hand to OOP and am having trouble getting my head around how to process the results. This is a query I'm using.

```
   $rows = $db->select("SELECT * FROM tblriskregister 
    WHERE riskSessionId=$riskSessionId ");
```

I can print out elements of the results by using $rows[0]['aname'].  But I don't know how to iterate through the results.  Everything is in $rows but no matter what I have tried I can't seem to iterate through. I've tried

```
    while($rows->num_rows >0) and
    $rows->fetch_assoc()
```

but everything I try doesn't work.  The initial query to the database has returned everything to $rows as an array but I can't work out how to go through it and print out my rows.

Comment: Have you followed the docs at all? This is quite clearly outlined.

Comment: you will need to study the code first to figure out how queries are handled in the code you are currently using

Comment: I don't have the docs as such but I did spend a couple of hours scouring the net to try and work it out myself before turning to SO.  Gerneral question.  Do you get reputation points for correcting punctuation and grammar?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with all results, just iterate it this way:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['field_name'];
    echo $row['other_field_name'];
}
```

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask questions.

Comment: Now that you've edited tell the OP why they should use your code. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thank  you @Felipe Duarte that was exactly what I was looking for.  I had tried a foreach before but not like rows as rows.  It was 2.30 in the morning when I posted before. Could hardly keep my eyes open.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use OOP, use objects instead of arrays to handle the results.

```
$result = mysqli_query("select * from table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result) {
   echo $row->fileName1;
   echo $row->fieldName2;
}
```

The function `mysqli_fetch_object` automatically loops through the results of the query.